# error message "The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call" in c# &mysql connection

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

Hi i developed an application in c# and using mysql as backend. I have used ADODB for connecting to DB. I use DSN for communicating.

Now i have problem i have to install at my clients place where there are 3 machines interconnected (LAN). out of which 1 is XP, 1laptop with win7 and other Desktop with win7. Every thing working perfect on Laptop and XP machine but when i try to run Application on Desktop with win 7 it give following error. Actually i am able to connect to this desktop with win7 (this is working as server) from other two machines. Data is getting inserted properly. So i dont understand what is the problem with this server machine. I am getting following error message.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.get_ReadTimeout()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream..ctor(Stream baseStream)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream..ctor(Stream baseStream, Encoding encoding, Boolean compress)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
at construction.clsConnect..ctor()
at construction.frmNewSupplierEntryForm..ctor()
at construction.frmMainMenu.supplierToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
```

It will be gr8 help if any one rectify my problem. I would like to mention here is that i have nt at all used this "Socket" related code in the whole project. So please guide me. I am absolutely stuck up due to this problem.
Thanking you

Comment: Is the server connected to an ipv6 enabled network?

Comment: Also, try compiling "x86" instead of "Any CPU".

Comment: yes probatly it is connected to ipv6 network. on monday i will go to client place to check that and will do some more changes then hopefully it will work.I will take ur point as well. i tried with the x86 instead of Any CPU. But it doesnt worked. I think is due to ipv6 network..